# Receiving error fault "Account Disabled" when making SOAP request

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I am making a request to https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx.  The request looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>user@email.com</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">123456</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Options/>
      <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>Master_User_Table</CustomerKey>
        <Properties>
          <Property>
            <Name>user_id</Name>
            <Value>12345</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>emailaddress</Name>
            <Value>test@fakeemail.com</Value>
          </Property>
        </Properties>
      </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In my user settings I have "Enabled" set to Yes, and "API User" set to Yes.  However, I'm getting this response:

```
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
    <faultcode xmlns:q0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">q0:Security</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Account Disabled</faultstring>
    <faultactor>https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</faultactor>
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was making a request to https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx, but I was part of the s7 bucket.  I just had to update the url to point to s7 and everything worked.